# How to restore database using mongodb compass?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb database in a dump folder which contain some bson and json files. I want to restore it using mongorestore, but I can't connect to the cluster through mongo shell. So I use mongo compass to connect but I have no clue how to restore it in the mongo compass.

Comment: you will need [3T Studio](https://studio3t.com/features/) for restoring a full database, Compass has no such feature.

Answer (score 2):

To create a database dump and then restore it, you need to have (have been installed) [tools for working with the database on your system](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/) - a set of utilities (executable files) of the command line for working with MongoDB,
such as: *mongodump*, *mongorestore*, *bsondump*, *mongoimport*, *mongoexport* and *other*...

The set of utilities supports all popular platforms. For example, system support by the *mongorestore* utility can be viewed [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#platform-support).

To install a set of utilities into your system, you need to use the installation instructions for your operating system: [Linux](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-linux/), [MacOS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-macos/), [Windows](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/).

Since problems can usually arise when using utilities on Windows, let's look at an example of installing and using utilities specifically for this system. We will be using Windows 10.

**So...**

1. Open MongoDB [Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools).
2. Select the desired operating system and package type on the page in
   the form. Downloading the archive!
3. Unpack the contents of the downloaded archive, for example, to the
   **C:\utilities** folder.
4. Further, in order for the system to see our utilities and avoid an
   error the utility

> command is not an internal or external command,
> executable program or batch file

, you must add a new entry to environment variables ([read more about it](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-windows/#make-the-db-tools-available-in-your-path-1)).

[image]

* *once environment variables are set, MongoDB utility commands can be executed from any directory of any console (simple console, PowerShell, IDE code editor console)*

* *You can`t use environment variables, but in this case, keep in mind that running utility commands will only be possible from the directory in which you placed the executable file. In other words, whenever you need to execute a console command of one of the utilities, you will need to change to the directory where the executable file is located!*

**Now it remains only to run the command to restore the database on your server, it will look like this - in the latest version of MongoDB, everything is as simple as impossible:**

```
mongorestore C:\backups\db

    // or, for example, specifying the host and port like this

mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 C:\backups\db

    // or like this

mongorestore --host localhost:27018 C:\backups\db
```

**Most Important!** Since the *--db* option for mongorestore is ***deprecated*** , please note that we do not specify the name of the database to restore the database to!
The name of the database where the data will be imported is the name of the directory in the db folder, in which, in turn, you should have dump files in *.bson* and *.json* formats.

If you specify a specific directory in which you have dumps, for example: ***C:\backups\db\my_app***, then running the command will result in an error -

> ... don't know what to do with file....

Also keep in mind that running the mongorestore command from the ***C:\backups\db*** directory will restore the dumps of all applications located in this directory (if any)!

Before 4 version of MongoDB, the mongorestore command could look like this (**deprecated**):

```
mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 --db name_your_db C:\backups\db\my_app  // a
mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 -d name_your_db C:\backups\db\my_app    // b

    // or short records:
    
mongorestore -h localhost --port 27017 -d name_your_db C:\backups\db\my_app      // a
mongorestore -h localhost:27017 -d name_your_db C:\backups\db\my_app             // b
mongorestore --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/name_your_db" C:\backups\db\my_app // c
```

In fact, there may be more options for using the command, with various options, using authorization on the server. In this case, only a few examples are given.

You can see the full list of options on the [official website](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#options).

**To create a dump, use the command:**

```
mongodump --out=C:\backups\db // <- to make dump all databases
mongodump -h localhost:27017 -d my_app --out=C:\backups\db // <- to create a dump of a specific single database
```

You can see the full list of options of mongodump on [the official website](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#options).

* *for Linux, commands are executed in a similar way*

Answer (score 0):

You run mongorestore runs from the system command line, not mongo shell. Use the Command Prompt in Windows or Terminal in OS X / Linux to enter the command and you should be good to go. The connection string will be the same one you used to connect through Compass.

Answer (score 0):

To restore you have to follow these steps carefully:-

1: **First check dump type** if it is a zip file then extract it.

2: open your cmd prompt and go to the folder where your database XYZ (folder) exists.

```
mi@sujeet-mishra:~/Downloads/dump$
```

Inside the dump, there is a folder called **XYZ** (folder of XYZ database)

Now run the command: mongorestore -db XYZ

```
mi@sujeet-mishra:~/Downloads/dump$ mongorestore -db XYZ
```

that's it, now refresh your MongoDB and you will get a DB named XYZ.

Comment: This does not answer the question about restoring the database using compass.